# Align windows in Gnome (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-11.04

Is there an application to dock windows to the left, right, top & bottom with keyboard shortcuts in Gnome? (Note: I'm using Ubuntu)

I know Ubuntu Unity can do so, but I don't want to use it because it slows down my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnome-shell also can do the same in GNOME 3.  It is not possible with metacity (the window manager).

However, you can maximize/un-maximize horizontal or vertically a window.  Go to System/Preferences/keyboard shortcuts.  Look for 'Window Management' and once inside there: Maximize window vertically and Maximize window horizontally.  In my case, I had set Ctrl-Alt-V and Ctrl-Alt-H, respectively.